# Add a file upload required field to Yesod form

Tags: haskell, yesod

Shalom!
I would like to add a file upload field to my form but cannot use as `fileAFormOpt` `fileAFormReq` are the wrong type. Is there no `fileFieldReq` function in Yesod?

Comment: Could you provide a code example? It's not quite cleay, why you can't use `filaAFormOpt` or `fileAFormReq`.